# react.js project don't work after npm audit fix --force

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I ran npm audit fix --force while at my lasts steps from a video teaching how to build a website-portfolio, when I saw a message and ran it whitout understanding, thinking the update of it will be fine.
After it I receive many errors about openssl etc.
I tried many steps but nothing work.
My actual message when I run npm start is the following :

> `Starting the development server...

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
> at handleParseError (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
> at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
> at Array. (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
> at Storage.finished (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
> C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
> at context.callback (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\the-portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }

> Node.js v18.14.0`

I am sure it is because npm audit fix --force

Can someone help please

I tried to delete node modules folder and package-lock.json and reinstall with npm install and still the same error.

Comment: try npm cache clear

Comment: @Wraithy just did it and same situation : 
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Answer (score 1):

- open the terminal and run npm uninstall react-scripts
- run npm install    react-scripts

Worked to fix everything for my case